# extracting data from 3D contour lines

Tags: python, 3d

I have a three dimensional numpy array of data, and three associated arrays giving the polar coordinates for each point. I would like to generate an isosurface of a given value in the 
original array, and extract the r, theta and phi values of points on that surface. In 2D I did this (in part following advice found here) as shown below (this also finds the percentage difference in r between the major and minor axes of what is assumed to be ellipsoidal data), but the matplotlib function contour does not work in 3D. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

def ellipsecalc(divret2real,r, theta):

```
time_e1 = time.time()

plt.figure()
plt.contour(divret2real, [.8])
plt.show()

cs=plt.contour(divret2real, [.3])
p = cs.collections[0].get_paths()[0]           # from matplotlib 
v = p.vertices                                 # interplated x,y positions of the contour
x = v[:,0]
y = v[:,1]

time_e2 = time.time()
print ('time for r at fixed plotting', time_e2 - time_e1, 'seconds')


rellipse = ndimage.map_coordinates(r, [[x],[y]], order=1)
thellipse = ndimage.map_coordinates(theta, [[x],[y]], order=1)
rellipse1d = rellipse.flatten()
thellipse1d = thellipse.flatten()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(thellipse1d, rellipse1d)
plt.show()

rellmax = np.amax(rellipse1d)
rellmin = np.amin(rellipse1d)

percrdiff = (((rellmax - rellmin)/2.) / ((rellmax + rellmin)/2.)) * 100.

rmaxref = np.argmax(rellipse1d)
thofrmax = thellipse1d[rmaxref]

print ('percentage difference, max and min axes', percrdiff)

time_e3 = time.time()
print ('time for r at fixed ac calc', time_e3 - time_e2, 'seconds')

return percrdiff, rellipse1d, thellipse1d, thofrmax
```

Comment: Can you add a tag for the language you are using above?  matlab or whatever it is?